# Как вывести значения из множеста или списка в текстовое поле

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tkinter

Имеется окно с жанрами, при нажатии на жанр в окне он сохраняется в set(). Как вывести сохраненные в set() данные в текстовое поле. Т.е хочу после выбора и подтверждения, выбранные жанры выходили в виде текста. Вместо set можно использовать и list это не принципиально как вам удобнее. Главное понять как выводить данные (из list или set) на текстовое поле на окне.

```
from tkinter import *
copy=set()
def window_with_janre():
    jenre_window = Tk()
    jenre_window.title("Выбор жанара.")
    jenre_window.geometry("650x400")
    jenre_window.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)


    button_janr1 = Button(jenre_window, text='Action and adventure', bg='gold', font='Arial 13', height=1, command=lambda: copy.add("Action and adventure"))
    button_janr1.place(x=20, y=20)

    button_janr2 = Button(jenre_window, text='Detective', bg='gold', font='Arial 13', height=1, command=lambda: copy.add("Detective"))
    button_janr2.place(x=20, y=60)

    button_janr3 = Button(jenre_window, text='Sci-fi', bg='gold', font='Arial 13', height=1, command=lambda: copy.add("Sci-fi"))
    button_janr3.place(x=20, y=100)

    button_janr4 = Button(jenre_window, text='Historical fiction', bg='gold', font='Arial 13', height=1, command=lambda: copy.add("Historical fiction"))
    button_janr4.place(x=20, y=140)

    button_janr5 = Button(jenre_window, text='Dystopia', bg='gold', font='Arial 13', height=1, command=lambda: copy.add("Dystopia"))
    button_janr5.place(x=20, y=180)

    button_janr6 = Button(jenre_window, text='Fantasy', bg='gold', font='Arial 13', height=1, command=lambda: copy.add("Fantasy"))
    button_janr6.place(x=20, y=220)

    button_janr7 = Button(jenre_window, text='Romance novel', bg='gold', font='Arial 13', height=1, command=lambda: copy.add("Romance novel"))
    button_janr7.place(x=20, y=260)

    button_janr8 = Button(jenre_window, text='Short stories', bg='gold', font='Arial 13', height=1, command=lambda: copy.add("Short stories"))
    button_janr8.place(x=20, y=300)

    button_janr9 = Button(jenre_window, text='Western', bg='gold', font='Arial 13', height=1, command=lambda: copy.add("Western"))
    button_janr9.place(x=20, y=340)

    button_janr10 = Button(jenre_window, text='Horror', bg='gold', font='Arial 13', height=1, command=lambda: copy.add("Horror"))
    button_janr10.place(x=250, y=20)

    button_janr11 = Button(jenre_window, text='Classic', bg='gold', font='Arial 13', height=1, command=lambda: copy.add("Classic"))
    button_janr11.place(x=250, y=60)
    jenre_window.mainloop()


window_with_janre()
```

Comment: не стоит называть copy - это имя встроенной функции. Не понятно событие "после выбора и подтверждения", в какое текстовое поле вы хотите получить вывод. в каком виде - построчно?

Comment: @splash58 я временно не подумав назвал так переменную, сейчас поменяю. Мне нужен сам принцип как именно выводить из set() и list() на окно в текстовом поле. Вид построчно или через запятую не принципиально.

Comment: вас устроил данный вам ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут лучше применить `insert()` у объекта `Text`. Например, создадим `Text` и присвоим его переменной `text_field`:

```
text_field = Text(jenre_window, width=40, height=10)
text_field.place(x=200, y=20)
```

Потом при нажатии на кнопку с жанром, можно добавлять выбр. жанр в `text_field` с помощью метода insert():

```
button_janr1 = Button(jenre_window, text='Action and adventure', bg='gold', font='Arial 13', height=1, command=lambda: text_field.insert(END, "Action and adventure" + "\n"))
```

Еще решение:

```
from tkinter import *

def window_with_janre():
    jenre_window = Tk()
    jenre_window.title("Выбор жанара.")
    jenre_window.geometry("650x400")
    jenre_window.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)

    selected_genres = ""
    def update_text_field():
        text_field.config(state=NORMAL)
        text_field.delete(1.0, END)
        text_field.insert(END, selected_genres)
        text_field.config(state=DISABLED)

    text_field = Text(jenre_window, width=40, height=10)
    text_field.place(x=200, y=20)
    text_field.config(state=DISABLED)

    button_janr1 = Button(jenre_window, text='Action and adventure', bg='gold', font='Arial 13', height=1, command=lambda: selected_genres += "Action and adventure" + ", " if selected_genres else "Action and adventure" + ", ", 
                                                                                                                                                                                             command=update_text_field)
    button_janr1.place(x=20, y=20)

    button_janr2 = Button(jenre_window, text='Detective', bg='gold', font='Arial 13', height=1, command=lambda: selected_genres += "Detective" + ", " if selected_genres else "Detective" + ", ", 
                                                                                                                                                                      command=update_text_field)
    button_janr2.place(x=20, y=60)
    # and so on
```

или так:

```
from tkinter import *

def window_with_janre():
    jenre_window = Tk()
    jenre_window.title("Выбор жанара.")
    jenre_window.geometry("650x400")
    jenre_window.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)

    selected_genres = []

    def update_text_field():
        text_field.config(state=NORMAL)
        text_field.delete(1.0, END)
        for genre in selected_genres:
            text_field.insert(END, genre + "\n")
        text_field.config(state=DISABLED)

    text_field = Text(jenre_window, width=40, height=10)
    text_field.place(x=200, y=20)
    text_field.config(state=DISABLED)

    button_janr1 = Button(jenre_window, text='Action and adventure', bg='gold', font='Arial 13', height=1, command=lambda: selected_genres.append("Action and adventure"))
    button_janr1.place(x=20, y=20)

    button_janr2 = Button(jenre_window, text='Detective', bg='gold', font='Arial 13', height=1, command=lambda: selected_genres.append("Detective"))
    button_janr2.place(x=20, y=60)
    #and so on 
    confirm_button = Button(jenre_window, text='Подтвердить', command=update_text_field)
    confirm_button.place(x=20, y=300)
```

Следующий код тоже может помочь:

```
from tkinter import *

def window_with_genres():
    genre_window = Tk()
    genre_window.title("Select Genres")
    genre_window.geometry("650x400")
    genre_window.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)

    selected_genres = ""

    def update_label():
        genre_label.config(text=selected_genres)

    genre_label = Label(genre_window, text="")
    genre_label.place(x=200, y=20)

    action_adventure_button = Button(genre_window, text="Action and Adventure", command=lambda: selected_genres.append("Action and Adventure"))
    action_adventure_button.place(x=20, y=20)

    detective_button = Button(genre_window, text="Detective", command=lambda: selected_genres.append("Detective"))
    detective_button.place(x=20, y=60)

    #and so on 
    confirm_button = Button(genre_window, text='Confirm', command=update_label)
    confirm_button.place(x=20, y=300)
```

Comment: А почему вы в третьем примере отклонились от своего же “лучшего” решения с insert?

Comment: 2 Вариант подошел